# Clustering in mule using Mule Management Console on local machine

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-cluster

I am new to Mule ESB.

I have downloaded `Mule Management Console(MMC)`.I have developed one simple application in which message(s) are put into queue which are then read by another queue. Now what i want to  have two MMC instances running and on stopping one mule instance all the message flows through second instance.

Please let me know how to approach about it. Can I do it on my local machine? I mean can i create cluster on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Mule based clustering.

Refer

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+High+Availability+HA+Clusters

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/1+-+Installing+the+Demo+Bundle

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Mule server doesn't allow you to link itself with two MMC instances at the same time thats because you register your mule server with MMC refer this: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Architecture+of+the+Mule+Management+Console.

There is a way to have other MMC instance but that MMC instance has to be passive when the other is already running, MuleSoft has documented this refer it here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Persisting+MMC+Data+to+Oracle

So, in your case, when one mmc instance is stopped you can start the other one.